# Device configuration in Eclipse to make the layouts

Tags: android

anybody knows what is the dimension and the pixel density of the Samsung Galaxy II to do the device configuration in Eclipse to make better the design of the layout? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy S 2's 4.3" display is 800x480 resolution, providing 217 pixels per inch.

Comment: Thank you. But how I can make the device configuration in Eclipse? The resolution is not the same that the screen dimension. If I don´t put the dimension the Graphical layout is not the same and if I put a button later when I run the app the button is in another place than the place that I have put.

Comment: if its the resolution of the virtual device u want to change, then go to Window -> Android Avd and Sdk Manager, now change the resolution of the virtual device u are using, u can do that by selecting your device and by clicking on edit.

Comment: I don´t want to change the resolution of my virtual device. In the general screen of the Eclipse, where you design the layout you can select 2.7 in QVGA, 3.2 in HVGA slider (ADP1)...and you can do your own custom device. But doing your custom device you must to put the device´s screen size and this is that I want to know to configure a layout like the Samsung Galaxy´s layout. Tank you.

Comment: ok, i have gone through the built in configurations, but what galaxy s2 need is 4.3(WVGA) which is not available, WVGA is for (800x480). To define a custom layout, select custom in the layout interface, and  click on new , now fill the names , and put xdpi as 217.71428 and ydpi as 218.49463. This should set your layout similar to samsung galaxy s2.